# Unable to get form input element states for dynamically added input elements in angularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```
<html>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
        app.controller('validateCtrl', function ($scope, $compile) {
            $scope.createField = function () {
                var lname = '<label>LastName : </label><input type="text" name="last" ng-model = "last" required/> Valid: {{myForm.last.$valid}}<br>';
                var tdiv = document.createElement("div");
                tdiv.innerHTML = lname;
                $compile(tdiv)($scope);
                document.getElementById("container").appendChild(tdiv);
            }
        });
    </script>
    <body>
        <h2>Validation Example</h2>
        <form ng-app="myApp"
              ng-controller="validateCtrl" 
              name="myForm">
            <div id="container">
                Firstname : <input type="text" name="first" ng-model="first" required/>
                Valid: {{myForm.first.$valid}} [ Here element state is displayed whether element is valid or not correctly but if we add element dynamically with create button it is not showing either valid or not. ]

            </div>
            <button type="button" ng-click="createField();" value="Create">Create</button>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Here element state is displayed whether element is valid or not correctly but if we add element dynamically with create button it is not showing either valid or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't working because you compile your dynamic inputs detached, thus they are unable to register themselves via `FormController`. To make it work you first need to insert your element into the DOM, and compile it right after. So basically just move your `$compile(tdiv)($scope);` one line down. In the end you should have this:

```
        $scope.createField = function () {
            var lname = '<label>LastName : </label><input type="text" name="last" ng-model = "last" required/> Valid: {{myForm.last.$valid}}<br>';
            var tdiv = document.createElement("div");
            tdiv.innerHTML = lname;
            document.getElementById("container").appendChild(tdiv);
            $compile(tdiv)($scope);
        }
```

Comment: If this answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.